# YouTube mobile site not recognising oauth session

Tags: oauth, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-channels

We are working on a web application that uses Google oauth to authenticate a user and the authorize our app to write a private playlist to their Youtube channel.  The oauth verification occurs and then we proceed to create a playlist and send tracks via the Youtube V3 api.  Once completed we redirect the user to the full playlist url I.e. http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAYLIST-ID and then your device detection kicks in and redirects user to mobile site as appropriate.  At this point (if on mobile site) we have found that the users signed in session is not recognised and as the playlist is private, therefore no videos are provided.  If the user selects sign in the session is automatically recognised.

Has anyone else experienced this or know of a fix?  Is it a known bug?  I was thinking of once creating the playlist to send the user to a a Google Service login page which would then redirect the user to YouTube but was hoping there might be a more elegant solution?

Patrick

Comment: I haven't seen this happen. Can you provide some code that can reproduce this so I'll look at it on my Android device? What device are you using?

Comment: Hi @ikai-lan,  thanks for your message and sorry for the delayed response. We have found this on default browser on Android on 4.0.3.  Without posting too much detail of the code I am working on an equivalent test is to go to gmail on your device, sign in, then enter a private playlist url(would have to be one in your account) directly into the browser.  It does not recognise the signed in session.  Let me know if you can reproduce as this is similar behaviour to our app

Comment: Is this just the stock browser? This seems to work for me on Chrome (I don't readily have a phone with stock browser available).

Comment: It definately occurs on stock browser on Android (that isnt Chrome - not sure what version Chrome became default?).  This also happens when the site we are making is loaded in the webview of our Android and iOS apps, its something we need to get to the bottom of but understand its difficult as there is only so much information I can post on public forums..

Comment: Incidentally it is possible to replicate this using User-Agent-Switcher extension for Chrome and Add-on for Firefox

Comment: @IkaiLan Were you able to look at and replicate this?